# What exactly does “walking around the house” mean?

Tags: difference, adverbs, word-in-context

I am confused of the word “around”.

1. A person is outside and walking along the house?
2. A person is inside the house walking in any direction.

Does it mean number 1 or 2? If both are correct, how can we distinguish which one is which when someone is using the word “around” in that context?

Comment: It's ambiguous. You can only tell from context, not from the sentence alone. It can mean either.

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible. You distinguish between the two by looking at the context with which they are spoken.